# How to show tab control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, .net-4.0, tabcontrol

I am developing a C# .NET web application using .NET Framework 4.0.

In that, I need to show a page with 3 tabs like our web browsers do. Each tab has a different functionality.

How can I create tab control in Visual Studio using the .NET Framework 4.0, is there any built in tab controls?

regards

Answer (score 14):

There's the AJAX control toolkit [tabs](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Tabs/Tabs.aspx) and [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/). I have used both and prefer jQuery UI. Microsoft officially includes/recommends jQuery with web applications.

If each tab has completely separate content, I would suggest rendering a simple, styled bar of links and have each element link to a new page/view. That way, hidden content isn't rendered until it's needed.

### jQuery UI Example

*Note that this doesn't have anything to do with .NET or Visual Studio; this is a purely client-side solution.*

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});

</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">Content 1</div>
    <div id="tabs-2">Content 2</div>
    <div id="tabs-3">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: dude, i dont want to use ajax

Comment: ...then don't. I said that I prefer the jQuery tabs.

Comment: how to use jquery in vs 2010?

Comment: i came to know vs 2010 has built in jquery dll but how to use it in my app for tab control? please help!

Comment: To use the jquery tabs in a Visual Studio project, make sure your page references the jquery and jquery UI libraries with a script tag, and then follow the instructions for turning HTML elements into tabs (many examples in the jquery UI tab documentation).

Comment: I added a full example as well.

Comment: Guys its very urgent.  in this app, the tab created but all the tabs  are joined together. i need some css code to seperate it as seperate tabs. please help me to seperate the tabs through css coding

Comment: and also the tab top corners must be rounded.